# convergence of singular values

Tags: matrices

I jus want to know how to show that if a matrix X converge to Y ( with respect to any matrix norm) then the ith singular value of X converge to the ith singular value of Y.

Thank you

Comment: Is this a homework problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm reading an article about rank minimization where they use this fact,  i think about caracteristic polynomial of transpose(X)*X, can we say that if a Polynom P converge to Q, then it's the same thing for the roots?

Answer (score 1):

This is stated by Weyl's inequality: for any two matrices $A$ and $\tilde A$ which are related by $A - \tilde A = E$, their corresponding singular values satisfy
$$
  | \tilde\sigma_i - \sigma_i | \le \| E \|_2.
$$

This is stated in http://www.math.msu.edu/~markiwen/Teaching/MTH995/Papers/SVD_Stewart.pdf, where also a reference is given. If you want to prove it yourself, it's rather easy when using the [Courant-Fischer min-max principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem) as a starting point.